Thrust on container due to effluxing fluid
we know that by F=dP/dt=vdm/dt=pav^2
where p is density and P is momentum.considering the hole really small compared to the container.
however by Bernoullis equation
Pressure(inside)= Presure(atm) + 1/2pv^2
i.e difference in pressure = pgh = 1/2pv^2
so force on container should be (difference in pressure)*(Area of cross section)= 1/2pv^2
these two do not match and every book suggests the first one.
Can someone help me(and tell me what is wrong with the second approach)
Thanks in advance

Are you familiar with the macroscopic momentum balance equation?

we know that by F=dP/dt=vdm/dt=pav^2 Where has this equation come from? Is v constant? Does it not change from 0 to v?

@ChetMiller I dont think so. I am in high school

When you wrote your first "we know" equation, where did it come from.

@ChetMiller ￼I thought of it this way Fdt=dm(change in velocity)    this would be due to elementary dm mass.

Your intuition on this was correct.  The net force is equal to the rate at charge of momentum.

@ChetMiller my doubt was why was the "1/2" term coming when we were equating the (pressure diff)(cross section area)=net run force on container?\
